# Google Service account setup with Tableau server

Tags: google-cloud-platform, migration, service-accounts, tableau-api

How can we Integrate Google Service account setup with Tableau Desktop server so that we can access BQ data in tableau to have the visualization for that data.

Comment: Have you tried this tutorial: https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/examples_googlebigquery.htm